# magento 1.9.4.1 Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::getFoundData()

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I have problem with search products on magento 1.9.4.1

i have this error

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext::getFoundData() in /var/www/vhosts/donordrives.com/m1.donordrives.com/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php on line 148\n'
```

I was looking for this problem, but did not understand how to correct the error.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: There is a app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext class that is being used instead of the class from the core (local class override)

Comment: Yes, I read it. But how do I fix the error?

Comment: Disable that overrided module and check working fine or note

Comment: Maybe I'm asking stupid questions, but where can I turn it off?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: There are no files in your path that would fit me, also i went /etc/modules/ and there also did not find the file

Answer (score 0):

**There is a app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext class that is being used instead of the class from the core (local class override)**

> Try To Disable Your Custom Module  :-

**/etc/Vendor_Module.xml**

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
      <modules>
          <vendor_module>
             <active>false</active>
             <codepool>local</codepool>
          </vendor_module>
      </modules>
</config>
```

**Set  false and Check**

Comment: your module name ????

Comment: i use default magento search module CatalogSearch, I do not understand what custom plugin you are talking about , i don't have any custom plugins for searching